# How to fix hole in step on plastic/vinyl porch?

Tags: porch

Listing my house for sale in a few weeks.
Have this hole in a porch step.
The porch is plastic/vinyl and I have no idea what brand or model it is.
What is an easy way to fix?
Can I get a similar material from home Depot to cut and screw on top of existing steps, and do it to all the steps so the look is consistent?
What would I use to cut the material to size?

[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hate to say this, but they look weak to be used as steps/treads.  They look like anybody with heels could pop a hole though them.  Just adding to the top might take the step rise out of code.  I would think about removing and replacing.

Comment: I agree with @crip659.  If you can't replace them entirely, maybe your best bet is to get something like aluminum plate with an anti-skid "sticker" to cover the entire tread.

Comment: I was thinking you could flood the area with epoxy and paint. But @Huesmann had a good idea with the traction sticker.

Answer (score 3):

You have three choices here.

What you currently have does not look like any material I have seen in the last 50 years. Not on stars or any place else. So it may be something proprietary, done many years ago by a small company.  If that is that case you will have to try to find a replacement. that probably is going to be fruitless.

Option two is to replace all the treads.

The third thing is based on your market.  In hot markets many homes are being sold as is and without inspections.  Do nothing. Save the money you would spend to correct the problem.

You should consult a realtor regarding this strategy. However remember you can spend money that does not matter to an anxious buyer because they want the house and are going to make it theirs as they want it. As an example we recently put my mother-in-law's home on the market.  She wanted me to do a weeks worth of work fussing with this and that. I did not have the time to spare. The realtor told her to sell as is.  It sold at the asking price in 48m hrs. Without any repairs.